# iPhone 4.0 SDK UIWebView crashes with DOMHTMLElement error

Tags: ios4, ios

My app have an UIWebView and I open a twitter oauth page with it.

when I open oauth page , it works well.

after I sign-in, it redirects to another page which have PIN code.

and It crashes down with logs below.

Is it a bug in 4.0 SDK?

```
2010-06-14 22:55:11.159 AllFx[1435:2003] -[DOMHTMLElement setHref:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x74e4040
2010-06-14 22:55:11.162 AllFx[1435:2003] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DOMHTMLElement setHref:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x74e4040'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02b6c919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02cba5de objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02b6e42b -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02ade116 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02addcd2 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   DataDetectorsUI                     0x0bde8ac4 -[WebTextIterator(DDExtensions) dd_doUrlificationForQuery:forResults:document:DOMWasModified:URLificationBlock:] + 1731
    6   DataDetectorsUI                     0x0bde2f09 -[DDOperation _doURLificationOnDocument] + 341
    7   DataDetectorsUI                     0x0bddff9c -[DDDetectionController _doURLificationOnWebThreadAndRelease:] + 563
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x02add42d __invoking___ + 29
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x02add301 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 145
    10  WebCore                             0x039fa2b3 _ZL15HandleAPISourcePv + 147
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x02b4dd7f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x02aac2cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x02aab7c6 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x02aab280 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x02aab1a1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    16  WebCore                             0x039943c3 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 483
    17  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x98552a19 _pthread_start + 345
    18  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9855289e thread_start + 34
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: I was able to recreate a similar stack using this URL.
When i use the subdomain "www." it loads the webpage correctly.
When I use the subdomain "m." it loads the webpage, but then terminates with an NSException. 
 
[theWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
   [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://m.facebook.com/facebook"]]];

I am also using 4.0 SDK.

Answer (score 4):

I've got it.
This might have been a problem with auto generating link.

Turn off all detection of your `UIWebView`.

In my case, detection of phone numbers was issues.

Answer (score 1):

Deactivating detection of links did it for me in the UIWebView!
I tried phone numbers first and that wasn't enough. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and, in my case, deactivating the phone number ditation did work.

```
webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

Very strange issue.